# Query returns nested object for BIT data type. How to get the bit value?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    username AS email,
    optin AS optional
    FROM user AS ua
            INNER JOIN user_preferences AS up ON up.user_id = ua.id
    WHERE ua.id = ${id}
```

I receive expected data, but it looks like this:

```
let queryResult = await MySQLQueryBuilder.getBasicUserData(userId);
```

The returned `queryResult` is:

```
{
    email: 'someuser@email';
    optional: { type: 'Buffer', data: [1] }
}
```

I was hoping to get something like this:

```
{
    email: 'someuser@email.com',
    optional: 1
}
```

Note that the data type of the `optin` column is `bit`.

Comment: It is BIT(1). So it is Bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this in the SQL query by converting the bit type to int type, for instance by adding 0 to it:

```
SELECT
    username AS email,
    optin+0 AS optional
    FROM user AS ua
            INNER JOIN user_preferences AS up ON up.user_id = ua.id
    WHERE ua.id = ${id}
```

You can see the behaviour you described even in [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u9QMPk2RoGSdbFF9PWEer5/0).